# Magento 2 - Rearrange the order of the Cart and Totals on the Order Summary Checkout Sidebar

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml, sidebar

I would like to move the Cart to be above the Totals in the Order Summary Checkout Sidebar. I have located both the Totals and Cart xml items in the `checkout_index_index.xml` in the Magento checkout module. I have created my own  `checkout_index_index.xml` file within my module, but not sure how to re-order the items within a block.

`checkout_index_index.xml` snippet from Checkout module in Magento:

```
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/totals</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary/totals</item>
        </item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- sort order for this totals is configured on admin panel-->
            <!-- Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order -->
            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cart Subtotal</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
                    <item name="notCalculatedMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Not yet calculated</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="itemsBefore" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- merge your components here -->
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/cart-items</item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="thumbnail" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail</item>
                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before_details</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/subtotal</item>
                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after_details</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I realized since it is not a `component` or `block` I cannot use the `<move>` or `after=` to move `cart_items`. So instead I used the `sortOrder` and set it to 0. That way it will always be before any other item in the `summary` block.

**Modified snippet from `checkout_index_index.xml`:**

```
<item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="shipping-information" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/view/shipping-information</item>
        </item>
        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

After that I ran `php bin:magento setup:upgrade` command, refreshed the page and `cart_items` appeared before `totals`.

Here is a before:

[image]

Here is an after:

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution to move the "Sign In" link at the top right in checkout but it didn't work. Could you help? I opened a question in case you know how to do it. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150355/magento-2-how-to-move-sign-in-block-in-checkout-below-progress-bar

Comment: under what xml parent did you place it? could you paste the complete xml, thx

Comment: How to move tax in order summary beofre show order total

Answer (score 4):

To modify just the sort order setting for the cart items you can add this crazy tree to your theme's Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml file:

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```