# Magento 2: How to move "Sign In" block in checkout below progress bar?

Tags: magento2, layout, design

In blank theme checkout, the "Sign In" link is located at the top right of the page.

I want to move it under the checkout progress bar.

I tried [this way](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146097/magento-2-rearrange-the-order-of-the-cart-and-totals-on-the-order-summary-chec) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Create the file : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/template/onepage.html`

And put this content inside :

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('progressBar') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('authentication') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('estimation') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
<div class="opc-wrapper">
    <ol class="opc" id="checkoutSteps">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('steps') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </ol>
</div>

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('sidebar') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

The original file is `apps/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html`

You might run a `magento setup:upgrade` to delete pub content in order to force Magento to use your new template file.

Answer (score 1):

By modifying layout we can move Position. Verified working in Magento 2.4.

In your theme file **app/design/frontend/Theme/package/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

Create checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">steps</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```